Javascript fetch POST request is showing up as a GET request on my backend (and stopping anything from working)
This is my POST request. It is used to send the data of the user to a backend PHP page. I did some debugging and
const fullusername = "<?php echo $to; ?>";
const personontheline = sessionStorage.getItem('name');
fetch('inc/AI2.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        fullname: fullusername, //variable
        personwhoclicked: personontheline //variable
    }) //continues to fetch errors

This is the backend. It shows that the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is a GET request for some reason. I'm not really good at PHP or Javascript. It doesn't work at all for some reason and I've spent hours trying to troubleshoot it. Its probably something dumb lol.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //do stuff
    }
} else {
    // Handle invalid requests
    echo "Invalid request       ".$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
    die();
}

I tried switching the method of the fetch to a GET method, but this slightly fixed the code as my code does not recognize the GET method's variables
if (isset($_GET['fullname']) AND isset($_GET['personwhoclicked'])) { //work } 
else{ echo "error"; }   

This is what burp suite makes it look like with post requests

This is what burp suite makes it look like with GET requests


Sorry but there's no way that fetch sends a GET when you told it to send a POST. My best guess is that you're monitoring the wrong request. Use your browser's Network tool as the primary way to monitor the fetch request.

I suspect there's a redirect on the server. Redirects use GET.

Check the Network panel of DevTools, look for a 30X response to the POST request followed by a GET request.

I suspect the issue is probably an automatic redirect that is converting the POST request to a GET. Adding redirect: 'manual' to your fetch options may stop that and let you dig directly into the response.
Below is the updated code with the redirect option:
fetch('inc/AI2.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        fullname: fullusername,
        personwhoclicked: personontheline
    }),
    redirect: 'manual'  // Prevents automatic redirects
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response); // Check the status and headers for redirect info
}).catch(error => console.error(error));

